# CSS Overlay on Embedded Vimeo Video not Working on Firefox Fullscreen

Tags: html, css, overlay, vimeo

I basically have a security requirement for a project I'm working on that requires me to put an overlay with simple text over a vimeo video that's embedded on a webpage. The text is security code that needs to be generated at page-load time, so it can't be embedded in the video directly.  I have an overlay code that works pretty well, but with Firefox, when I make the video fullscreen, the overlay disappears.  It works for Chrome and Safari.  I'm not a real front-end pro, so I cobbled together some excellent examples of overlays and have been hacking away at this for a couple of weeks now.
Unfortunately, I inherited this project and the site is in Wordpress, but has a lot of custom requirements, so there's a depth of the code that's a little challenging to wade through.

HTML

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">   
    <div class="wpb_video_wrapper">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/zzzzzzzz" width="900" height="506" frameborder="0" title="The Battle against Hate (Context 4)" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>               
        <div id="vidOverlays">
            <span id="vidOverlayTop">--------</span>
            <span id="vidOverlayTitle">[CUSTOM SECURITY TEXT HERE]</span>
            <span id="vidOverlayBottom">--------</span>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wpb_video_wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#vidOverlays {
    position:absolute; 
    bottom: 40px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    right: 0px;
    color: #cccccc;
    background-color: #2a3132; 
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2147483647!important;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-align: center;
}
#vidOverlayTop { 
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 2px; 
    opacity: 0.33;
    z-index: 2147483647!important;
}
#vidOverlayBottom {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 2px; 
    opacity: 0.33;
    z-index: 2147483647!important;
}
#vidOverlayTitle {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    padding: 2px;   
    z-index: 2147483647!important;
}
```

So again, I get the overlay in Chrome and Safari both in normal embedded mode and fullscreen mode, but in Firefox it works on non-fullscreen mode but when I go to fullscreen the overlay disappears. I'm guessing this has to do with how the browsers are handling video tags, but I can't put my finder on a solution. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Browser Versions:

- Chrome: 49.0
- Safari: 9.0.3
- Firefox: 46.0b1

As a follow-up, if anyone has a good strategy for doing this via a method other than something CSS-based, I'd love to hear it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you asked this six months ago, but I was having same problem and I found solution (for Firefox, it still doesn't work on Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge). You just need to delete styling for .wpb_video_wrapper so your code would look like:

```css
#vidOverlays {
 position:absolute; 
 bottom: 40px;
 /* width: 100%; */
 right: 0px;
 color: #cccccc;
 background-color: #2a3132; 
 display: inline-block;
 z-index: 2147483647!important;
 opacity: 0.5;
 text-align: center;
}
#vidOverlayTop { 
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 padding-top: 2px; 
 opacity: 0.33;
 z-index: 2147483647!important;
}
#vidOverlayBottom {
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 padding-bottom: 2px; 
 opacity: 0.33;
 z-index: 2147483647!important;
}
#vidOverlayTitle {
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 padding: 2px;   
 z-index: 2147483647!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_wrapper">   
 <div class="wpb_video_wrapper">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/184455304" width="900" height="506" frameborder="0" title="The Battle against Hate (Context 4)" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>               
  <div id="vidOverlays">
   <span id="vidOverlayTop">--------</span>
   <span id="vidOverlayTitle">[CUSTOM SECURITY TEXT HERE]</span>
   <span id="vidOverlayBottom">--------</span>
  </div>      
 </div>
</div>
```